# Taylor series expansion application

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I can not understand this step that the teacher did and I do not understand how she applied the Taylor series and which of the formulas she used. I already searched the Internet but found no formula that would be useful to me.

Step:
$$mc^2\bigg[1+\Big(\frac{\vec{p}c}{mc^2}\Big)^2\bigg]^{1/2}\approx mc^2\bigg[1+\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\vec{p}c}{mc^2}\Big)^2\bigg]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series of $(1+x)^n$ at $0$ is also known as the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) or generalized binomial theorem. It converges for $|x|<1$ and is given by

$$
(1+x)^n\approx 1+nx
$$

Putting $n=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\left(\frac{pc}{mc^2}\right)^2$ gives the required result.